# Does Credit affect M1?

Tags: macroeconomics

Customer #1 deposits a million dollars in the bank (demand deposit). The bank loans a million dollars to customer #2. Customer #2 puts the million dollars back into the bank for now (demand deposit). The bank now has two million dollars in demand deposit accounts. Did M1 just increase by one million dollars?

Comment: Yes, the loan increases the money supply (though in practice the bank makes the loan by crediting Customer#2's account matching that customer's new liability to the bank, rather than giving the customer cash).